# iOS TwitVid SDK not sending request

Tags: ios, twitter

I am trying to use the built in iOS 5 Twitter framework and the TwitVid SDK to upload a video to twitter.

Steps I am taking:

1) Use TWRequest to get a signed request.

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:[accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter] withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:[error description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    }
    else if (granted) {
        NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:[accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter]];
        if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {
            ACAccount *account = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

            NSURL *spURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"];
            TWRequest *twRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:spURL parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
            [twRequest setAccount:account];
            NSURLRequest *signedURLRequest = [twRequest signedURLRequest];
```

2) Create an instance of TwitVid and fire off an upload request

```
TwitVid *twitVid = [[TwitVid alloc] initWithSource:@"Test" delegate:self];
[twitVid uploadWithMediaFileAtPath:moviePath offset:0 message:@"Test Message" mediaID:nil playlistID:nil vidResponseParent:nil userTags:nil geoLatitude:nil geoLongitude:nil tags:nil categoryID:nil description:@"upload test" title:@"The title" xVerifyCredentialsAuthorization:[signedURLRequest valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"] xAuthServiceProvider:[spURL absoluteString]];
```

The first time I did this, I got some error back from the appropriate delegate method, and assumed it was a signing issue (I had some bugs in my code there). Now, no matter what I do, I get NOTHING in any of my delegate methods. Its not sending data, no response is received - nothing. I am at a loss of what to do. Any ideas?